# How to send pdf or image to a specific whatsapp contact?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, whatsapp

Tried out these following code snippets to send pdf, image and text. When used ACTION_VIEW the particular whatsapp chat is opening, text is getting sent but can't able to send the pdf or image. Please help with appropriate code snippet for the following problem I am facing.

The methods which I tried are as follows:

```
PackageManager pm = bill_layout.this.getPackageManager();
 try {
     Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     waIntent.setType("application/pdf");
     String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
     PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
     waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
     waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
 } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
     Toast.makeText(bill_layout.this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
             .show();
 }


try {
   String longUrl="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/glossy-radio-280106.appspot.com/o/19c48c9d-3f83-4a8f-a296-fe0ea
     Bitly bitly= Bit.ly("o_1gduh4caf3");
     shorturl=bitly.shorten(longUrl);
   String text= "shorturl";// Replace with your message.
   String toNumber = "91xxxxxxxxxx"; // Replace with mobile phone number without +Sign or leading zeros, but with country code
   //Suppose your country is India and your phone number is “xxxxxxxxxx”, then you need to send “91xxxxxxxxxx”.
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+toNumber +"&text="+ URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8"))
           "text/plain");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"okay");
   intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
   startActivity(intent); }
catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();}


PackageManager pm1=getPackageManager();
 try {
     String toNumber = "91xxxxxxxxxx"; // Replace with mobile phone number without +Sign or leading zeros, but with country co
     //Suppose your country is India and your phone number is “xxxxxxxxxx”, then you need to send “91xxxxxxxxxx”.
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:"+ toNumber));
     sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"test1");
     sendIntent.putExtra("chat",true);
     startActivity(sendIntent);}


catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     Toast.makeText(bill_layout.this,"it may be you dont have whats app",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
 File f=new File("path to the file");
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("gs://glossy-radio-280106.appspot.com/19c48c9d-3f83-4a8f-a296-fe0eaf4488c4.pdf");
 sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
 sendIntent.setType("application/pdf");
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
 sendIntent.putExtra("jid","918824525121"+"@s.whatsapp.net");
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"sample text you want to send along with the image");
 startActivity(sendIntent);
 PackageManager pm = bill_layout.this.getPackageManager();
     String formattedNumber ="91xxxxxxxxxx";
     try{
         Intent sendIntent =new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
         sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
         sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
         sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Card Set ");
         sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,formattedNumber);
         sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
         sendIntent.putExtra("jid", formattedNumber +"@s.whatsapp.net");
         sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
         bill_layout.this.startActivity(sendIntent);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Toast.makeText(bill_layout.this,"Error/n"+ e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set you type i.e file, image or text.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
File f=new File("Your file path");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
sendIntent.setType("image");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("91xxxxxxxxxx")+"@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Sample text");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```